# OpenStack - Web console connection refused

Tags: openstack

Just getting started with OpenStack.
got everything set up on a Ubuntu VM (under Parallels).
When I attempt to log into the browser console as admin (the password was set during the DevStack install) - I get:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.211.55.16', port=8774): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/a586870bde4c4dfc993dc40cab8047b7/extensions (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I am however able to run CLI commands such as keystone-tenant-list, and all others, on the actual server.
I made sure that I'm able to ping the virtual Ubuntu host from my Mac. When I first enter http://myhost.mydomain I do get a login page, but, as soon as I enter admin's credentials - I get this ugly (and super long error)

What things could I check to fix this?

Comment: I just check, and nothing is listening on port 8774. Is there a command I could use to start nova service manually?

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:
1) Wiped clean my Ubuntu host
2) Followed set-by-step instructions here: http://www.stackgeek.com/guides/gettingstarted.html
Everything now works without a glitch.